# Make a route only accessible in debug mode with flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a bunch of routes that I only want accessible in debug mode. Is there a decorator or something that allows me to do this or do I have to comment/delete the code entirely?
Example:

```py
@debug_only
@app.route("/send_data/<data>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def send_data(data):
    return jsonfy("{'data': data}")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flask does not provide any built-in decorator for this. Write a decorator that checks `current_app.debug` and returns a 404 if it's not in debug mode.

```py
from functools import wraps
from flask import current_app, abort

def debug_only(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(**kwargs):
        if not current_app.debug:
            abort(404)

        return f(**kwargs)

    return wrapped

@app.route("/debug")
@debug_only
def debug_info():
    ...
```